# How to order by a specific order in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have this `cars` collection and I want to query them by color in a specific order so let's say red -> blue -> green -> pink.

I have this query:

```
cont carsQuery = query(carsCollection, orderBy('color', 'asc'))
```

but this only lets me query cars in an alphabetical order. So is there a specific way to let me set a specific order for me to query data in?

Or if it's not possible to query the data in a specific order then can you give me examples as to how I could sort it manually on the frontend? (in JavaScript preferably)

I have tried setting indexes on the firebase console but can't seem to be able to set a specific order there.

Comment: It's not possible with Firestore's own queries. You will have to sort the documents yourself.  I suggest making an attempt at that first, then post your code here if it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Why not sort the data after you retrieve it? A database query is not a replacement for advanced sorting.